# Could not parse version constraint

Tags: php, class, composer-php

I can't add a class(**Jalali DateTime Class for PHP**) to my project and have an

```
ERROR: [UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint :dev-master: Invalid version string ":dev-master"
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Important note**: Jalali DateTime Class for PHP is **no longer actively maintained** and shouldn't be implemented in new code, as no functionality or security updates will be provided in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You somehow managed to sneak in a colon "`:`" into the branch name, and this confuses Composer.

Remove the colon, and it should work. However, please take the comment from above into consideration:

1. If the library isn't maintained anymore: Look for alternatives now before you start using it. It is the most convenient time to do.
2. Do not require "dev-master" at all, always require a tagged and released version. This will make your life much easier later on, when you add more dependencies and maybe update them.